# Run only integration tests on a Maven exec

Tags: maven, grails, grails-maven

I want to run only my integration tests using the grails-maven-plugin. I setup a profile to run the exec command as such:

```
   <profile>
        <id>run-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
                    <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${grails.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>grails-integration-tests</id>
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <command>test-app</command>
                                <env>integration</env>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

The problem is to run only the integration tests the grails command looks like: 
`grails test-app integration:` 
With the colon at the end of integration, so when I do

```
<args>integration:</args>
```

This throws:

```
BasicLazyInitializer: Javassist Enhancement failed: <my classes in integration tests>
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: hasProperty for class: groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
```

So basically I need to figure out how to pass the argument `integration:` into the maven exec, but I think maven doesn't like the colon.

Comment: Have you tried `-integration`?

Comment: That throws the same errors, but then continues on and runs the integration tests as expected. As a side note, when I run without the args tag, it runs both unit tests and integration tests, without any errors.

Comment: I think I'm just going to end up skipping the default maven test phase which runs the unit tests with <code>-DskipTests=true</code> and having the exec run both unit and integration tests. Thanks for the help @dmahapatro!

Comment: You can run only integration test with this command as well if needed: `mvn grails:exec -Dcommand=test-app -Dargs="-integration"`